# Header template wont alway pull up css

Tags: php, css

I am new to php, but suspect there is a simple solution that I am not aware of.
I have made a template for the header on every page, but when the user loads pages the css page changes in relation to their current page. 
How do I have php track how many levels up in a folder the user is so I can pull the css from anywhere in the website?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../templates/css/css.css" type="text/css" />
```

That is my current link to css, but for a page further down in folders I need it to add additional `../`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an absolute path from the root of the website (note, no ".." just a "/"):

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/templates/css/css.css' type='text/css' />
```

Will always work, as long as your css is at:

```
http://yourwebsite.com/templates/css/css.css
```

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't be using a relative path then. Why not just do something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.mysite.com/templates/css/css.css" type="text/css" />
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/css/css.css" type="text/css" />
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?>/templates/css/css.css" type="text/css" />
```

whichever suits your needs - since you may be working locally and have a strange file structure, or a shared style directory for example

Answer (score 0):

The best method is to use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?>/templates/css/css.css" type="text/css" />
```